# Flink batch job wait for kafka offset commit interval

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

I have a Flink batch job which reads from kafka and writes to S3. The current strategy of this job is to read

**From:** the committed offset in Kafka(if there is no committed offset, then read from the earliest offset)

**To:** the latest offset at the start of the job.

So I basically have my Kafka consumer as follows:

```
KafkaSource.<T>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(resolvedBootstrapBroker)
                .setTopics(List.of("TOPIC_0"))
                .setGroupId(consumerGroupId)
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST))
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(deserializationSchema)
                .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                .setProperties(additionalProperties)
                .build();
```

I also have disabled checkpointing, committing offset on checkpoints, because checkpoints are anyway disabled in Batch mode.I have enabled auto commit as follows:

```
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        properties.setProperty("commit.offsets.on.checkpoint", "false");
```

The problem I am having is offsets are not getting committed to Kafka. I understand that the Flink kafka consumer does not use these offsets. But in my case, since it is a batch job, I need to guarantee that the offsets are committed back to kafka. Currently we have very few records and the job runs only for 1241 ms. I even tried with committing the offsets once every 100 ms as in the example above. But no luck. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Flink `KafkaSource` only commits offsets back when checkpointing is enabled, as explained on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#consumer-offset-committing. Since checkpointing can't be enabled in batch mode, offsets are also not committed back to Kafka.

Looking at your source code, you're `setProperties` while the documentation talks about `setProperty` https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#additional-properties - Perhaps that's the issue?